# Is there a fast method to extract bits by index (not just masking)?

Tags: language-agnostic, bitmask

I have a certain binary number for example: 11110000
And a mask with exactly 4 bits set: 10101010
Im searching for a fast operation that would return the 4 bits of the input corresponding to the positions where the mask is set:

11110000
10101010
output:1100

In here I use a u8 to u4 but imagine this for u64 to u32. Is there a fast way to do this (in Rust or C) without looping?

I tried looping the indexes, and linear decomposition. Both are very slow as one requires looping the other requires a matrix decomposition.

Comment: Don't spam tags. If you want Rust or C, then remove C++ and Javascript tags.

Comment: I do not know what is *"mask with exactly 4 bits set"* and how is related to the expected output. I do not see any relationship between them

Comment: Why do you need that result? It's not clear what the purpose is (this sort of question usually ends with a popcount but that doesn't seem to be the case here)

Comment: @0___________ they have a bitmask with n bits set, they want to know which of the set bits of the mask matched, as an n-bits result (n=4). So basically the bitmask "compacted" to drop all the bits set to 0 in the mask.

Comment: If there are always exacly 4 bits set you can iterate through an array of 4 bit positions or masks.

Comment: When your mask is known, can't you split your mask into 4 masks, each with one bit and then shift the result of each mask to the bit where you want to have it stored in your output? [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ccda103ac2c5a6f061e81d4bb7db464) is what I mean with your concrete example. I'd think this'd be a pretty fast operation

Comment: @0___________ "that would return the 4 bits of the input corresponding to the positions where the mask is set" not really sure how to make that more clear, everyone else seemed to understand the relationship between the expected output and the mask

Comment: FWIW this request looks to be the PEXT instruction from BMI2 (however that is extremely slow on AMD so it should be considered intel-only, not sure whether it even exists in ARM or RISCV). https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091979/8182118 seems to essentially be this question in C.

Comment: @JonasFassbender yes thats a good idea (which would be the equivalent of a linear decomposition where the basis are the 4 different vectors) it works well but scales poorly for u32 and above. I wondered if there was a faster way

Comment: @Masklinn I wanted this to control a bit better conversion from integers with many bits to integer with less bits

Comment: @JonasFassbender FWIW Godbolt supports Rust and is better / more convenient than the playground for this sort of demos, [here is your snippet there](https://godbolt.org/z/1qe95nnnq).

Comment: @Haris its a general bit manipulation question, the time complexity is is at the same order for both languages. Besides not really sure how to go about here as i think opening the same question for two different languages could be considered spam?

Comment: There are c intrinsics _pext_u32 and _pext_u64 in <immintrin.h> as part of the BMI2 instruction set extension which should be able to do this pretty fast if you don't mind using non-standard x86_64.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add the `language-agnostic` tag to such a question. And no, it wouldn't be considered spam, I doubt a question about `nullptr`, tagged C23, would be closed as a duplicate for a C++ question about `nullptr`.

Comment: @SimonGoater thats a good start and thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you can preprocess your selection mask, then you can do this in log(width) number of mask-and-shift operations.

If your selection mask has any odd-sized gaps in it, then you can first apply a mask of bits to shift one position to the right, with the result that there will only be even-sized gaps between the bits you want.

Starting with a selection mask of `10101010`, for example, the bits to shift to the right 1 place are `00100010`.  After shifting those bits, the new selection mask to apply is `10011001`, which has only even-sized gaps.

Then there is a mask for shifting 2 positions to the right that will make all your gap sizes divisible by 4: `10011001` -> `10000111`

If you continue this way until the gap size is divisible by the word size, then there won't be any gaps: `10000111` -> `00001111`

To calculate these masks, first calculate the total shift required for each bit position.  The first mask clears the 1 bit from all odd total shifts.  The second mask clears the 2 bits, etc.